# How can I compare dates with different formats?

Tags: javascript

I don't know why, but I have two kind of dates.
One of them has this format

```
2011-11-03T15:28:03.333
```

The other one has this format

```
wed mar 05 20014 00:00: 00 GMT+0100 (W.Europe Standard Time)
```

How can I compare these?

Comment: And so what are you looking for?

Comment: i want to do something like this if(item.date > itemTwo.date) then ...  but when i did it that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Date constructor for that, it can "understand" a lot of different date formats:

```
var d1 = new Date('2011-11-03T15:28:03.333');
var d2 = new Date('wed mar 05 20014 00:00: 00 GMT+0100 (W.Europe Standard Time)');

d1 > d2 === false;
d2 > d1 === true;
```

In case `Date` constructor cannot handle your format in a specific browser (might happen) you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)